# Send Signature to AWS JS SDK from server, instead of using plain text secret key

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, salesforce, aws-sdk

Is there a way to send signed version of secret key to `AWS JS SDK`, instead of sending secret Key adn access key in plain text. I am using `Salesforce` and would like to create a signature in `Salesforce` and send it to `Javascript` (or VF page) the signature which can then be used in AWS SDK callouts, instead of giving the secret key on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

It's good that you see the obvious problem with embedding your credentials into the client.

Amazon [Security Token Service (STS)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_Welcome.html) is one solution to this issue.

Your application back-end systems send a request for temporary credentials to STS.  These credentials allow the entity possessing them to perform only actions authorized by the token, which is a third attribute added to the usual (access key id, access key secret) tuple, and the authority is valid only until the token expires.  Note that the token doesn't use your access key and secret, it actually comes with its own access key and secret, all of which are short-lived and "disposable."

In a sense, this is fairly well described by the phrase you used, "send signed version of secret key."  It's a disposable delegation of authority, in a sense.

See also http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I have never used or looked at STS at all. Let me take a look at it and will try the approach that you suggested. I will see how I can get the token back.

Comment: Hello Michael, I tried making a call to STS to get the Session Token, however I get an error - Status:  Found and StatusCode = 302. Do you know what this means. Following is the information I made a GET Call to https://sts.amazonaws.com with the following parameters action=GetSessionToken&version=2011-06-15 and had sent Authorization Header with Signature of V4.

Comment: Based on the name, GetSessionToken does sound like it would be what you want, but it isn't. Actually, it's "AssumeRole" that you want.  It returns temporary credentials which, when used, will permit *only* the actions allowed by the specified role *and* allowed by the policy document you send with your request.  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html

Comment: Thanks Michael for responding. I just tried AssumeRole as well, I get same error - Status- Found, Status Code - 302 - Following is the Canonical Request that I am sending - GET
/
action=AssumeRole&rolearn=arn%3Aaws%3Aiam%3A%3A66611724%3Auser%2FTestUser&rolesessionname=2&version=2011-06-15
host:sts.amazonaws.com
x-amz-date:20160402T031024Z

host;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855. Do you happen to a very basic sample request that you have for getting the sessiontoken..

Comment: Michael, I get the following error, looks like I am passed the signature issue and hopefully other issue - <ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>User arn:aws:iam::669117241080:user/TestUser is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::66911724:user/TestUser</Message>
  </Error>
  <RequestId>bdcce40a-f8ec-11e5-b1f8-973e9a8e5802</RequestId>
</ErrorResponse>
Thanks again a lot for helping

Comment: Michael, So I am finally able to get that working and get Session Token. However if I pass only Session Token AWS. Credentials, it gives me 'Credential Error'. Looks like the JS SDK is still expecting me to pass Secret Key to it. Do you know what I am doing wrong - Here is what I have AWS.Credentials = new AWS.Credentials({sessionToken:sessionTokenReturned});

Comment: The response from AssumeRole will include an alternate accesskeyid and secret, along with the token, all of which you'll expose.  Your error, above, was that you need to create an IAM role and try to assume it -- it looks as if you passed your user ARN in the request, rather than a role.  GetSessionToken is *not* what you want -- those credentials cannot be restricted by role or policy, and they carry all the authority of the requesting account -- which is too much to expose.

Answer (score 0):

I am finally able to make a call to STS from Salesforce using Apex Code, all thanks to Michael. Which then returns the Session Token, Temp Access Key and Temp Secret Key. Following is the gist of the code that I used to make a call to AWS STS.

---

```
public void  testGetSessionToken() { 
        method = HttpMethod.XGET;
        createSigningKey(AWS_SECRET_KEY_ID ) ;
        service = 'sts';
        resource = '/';

    //  Create all of the bits and pieces using all utility functions above
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod(method.name().removeStart('X'));
        setQueryParam('Version', '2011-06-15'); 
        setQueryParam('Action', 'AssumeRole'); 
        setQUeryParam('RoleArn', 'arn:aws:iam::669117241099:role/TestRole');
        setQueryParam('RoleSessionName', 'Swai');       
        String formatedDate = requestTime.formatGmt('yyyyMMdd') + 'T' + '03' + requestTime.formatGmt('mmss') + 'Z';
        setHeader('X-Amz-Date', formatedDate ); 
        setHeader('host', endpoint.getHost()); 

        finalEndpoint = 'https://sts.amazonaws.com' + resource + '?Version=2011-06-15&Action=AssumeRole&RoleArn=arn:aws:iam::559117241080:role/TestRole&RoleSessionName=Swai';
        request.setEndpoint(finalEndpoint);
        String[] headerKeys = new String[0];
        String authHeader = createAuthorizationHeader(); //This is the method that gets the signature)
        request.setHeader( 'host', 'sts.amazonaws.com');
        request.setHeader( 'X-Amz-Date', formatedDate );
        request.setHeader( 'Authorization', authHeader);
        HttpResponse response = new Http().send(request);
        // Parse XML to get SessionToken 
        XMLStreamReader xmlrdr = response.getXmlStreamReader();
        while (xmlrdr.hasNext()) { 
            if (xmlrdr.getEventType() == XMLTag.START_ELEMENT ) { 
                if (xmlrdr.getLocalName() == 'SessionToken') { 
                    while (xmlrdr.hasNext() && xmlrdr.getEventType() != XMLTag.END_ELEMENT){
                        if (xmlrdr.getEventType() == XMLTag.CHARACTERS) { 
                            forPageSessionToken = xmlrdr.getText();
                            break;
                        } else if (xmlrdr.hasNext()) xmlrdr.next();
                          else break;
                    }   
                } else if (xmlrdr.getLocalName() == 'AccessKeyId') { 
                    while (xmlrdr.hasNext() && xmlrdr.getEventType() != XMLTag.END_ELEMENT){
                        if (xmlrdr.getEventType() == XMLTag.CHARACTERS) { 
                            forPageTempAccessKeyId = xmlrdr.getText();
                            break;
                        } else if (xmlrdr.hasNext()) xmlrdr.next();
                          else break;
                    }   
                } else if (xmlrdr.getLocalName() == 'SecretAccessKey') { 
                    while (xmlrdr.hasNext() && xmlrdr.getEventType() != XMLTag.END_ELEMENT){
                        if (xmlrdr.getEventType() == XMLTag.CHARACTERS) { 
                            forPageTempSecretAccessKey  = xmlrdr.getText();
                            break;
                        } else if (xmlrdr.hasNext()) xmlrdr.next();
                          else break;
                    }   
                }
                else if (xmlrdr.hasNext()) xmlrdr.next();
                else break;                     
            } else if (xmlrdr.hasNext()) xmlrdr.next();
            else break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot Michael for being so helpful and for your prompt responses. I am posting the solution that I have here so that it can benefit others, and hopefully not be stuck for this long.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for the same kind of code and this is somewhat helpful also. I was wondering if you can please share code for createSigningKey(), createAuthorizationHeader(). 

I am getting problem in generating the signature for https request.
Thanks